Calculate optimal spacing of vertical magnetometer configuration in Magnetic Ground Survey
I have a vertical magnetometer configuration, and measure lines on the ground. I want to calculate the optimal spacing, based on the interpolation between the lines. Applying the generalized multivariate Gaussian likelihood function:
$L(B_m, B_t, P)=exp(-\frac{1}{2} [B_m-B_t]\, P^{-1} \,[B_m-B_t]^T)$
$B_m$ is the measured vector with $B_x$, $B_y$, and $B_z$ components, $B_t$ the respective interpolated values, $P$ the covariance matrix. This was originally used as a probability criteria for assigning a location to a magnetic map. Let's denote that probability as confidence score. On 1D, if we only have two measured points on the edge, should I then measure the Magnetic field and create a Graph $p(x)$ and fit it with a function similar to the one above, also Gaussian. Is it sufficient if I assume:
$p(x)=exp(-a\,(x-d)^2) + exp(-a\,(x+d)^2)$ and fit it to the measured probability distribution? Or would I need a covariance matrix as well, and not simply be allowed to see it in 1d?
I appreciate any help!
